# Attach onClick analytics tracking code in a href link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

I'm pretty new with JavaScript and jQuery and i'm having a hard time attaching onClick Google Analytics tracking inside an A link in our website redesign using jQuery.

I know that I can just do this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'URL']);">link</a>
```

However SharePoint html field deletes the onClick code whenever I put it there so I need a script that does that for me.

So far I have this:

```
<a class="tracking" href="URL">Read PDF</a>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".tracking").click(function() {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', 'url']);
    });
});
```

The clicked PDF doesn't show up in the real time analytics page when I checked. So I need something that would ensure that when the link is clicked, it shows up in the Analytics tracker in real time. Can I use a script that adds the onClick tracking event inside the A link.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you're trying to track `_trackPageview` on a link? Usually this onClick method is used to track `_trackEvent`. Page views are handled by the main tracking code you should have pasted on every page of you site

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, to get Google Analytics to track behavior "correctly," we need this little workaround. Google Analytics does not track PDF views by default, and our bounce rate metrics would be off by a lot if we don't count PDF clicks as "engagement." We typically reserve track events for things like item clicks within swf files, and other on-page actions that don't launch other windows.

Comment: Oo I see it makes more sense, let me give you an answer for this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a page view with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tracking").click(function() {
        ga('send','pageview','my-pdf-document')
    });
});
```

You can actually pass even more data. See the official doc here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#send

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/my-pdf.pdf',
  'title': 'My PDF Title'
});
```

UPDATE

You could definitely use your href dynamically like this

```
ga('send','pageview', $(this).attr('href'));
```

or even use some HTML-5, you can have your link like this:

```
<a href="/mypdf.pdf" class="tracking" data-title="mypdf-title">link</a>
```

and do

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'page': $(this).attr("href"),
    'title': $(this).data("title")
});
```

EDIT 2

If you're still using ga.js, you can do it this way then:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $(this).attr('href')]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I added a hitCallback to check if it really sends the data but I don't get any alerts. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StormingStorms/ffeL8/) of my code. We also have multiple PDF links that needs tracking in one page so is it also possible to use this.href so I don't need to duplicate multiple instances of this GA tracking per PDF?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how you can include data in your tracking. For your JSFIDDLE, the callback doesn't work because you need to load the Google js in order to have your `ga` methods working

Comment: O and also, you don't need the `$` in your `.ready(function($)`. Just to be clearer reagrding the library you need to load, you need to of course have the analytics.js loaded on your page (as I assumed you would) https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Comment: Oh right. I realized that when I sent the comment. Anyway I think that I cannot use the ga('send', 'pageview') code because our master page use this:
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXX-Y']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
inside the analytics.js. We have no way of editing the master page to change it to ga so we need another work around for this :(

Comment: Then you can do what I just added to my answer `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', $(this).attr('href')]);` that should work with the ga.js