# Keeping Track of my Downloads using Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

hope you're doing amazing!

I want to keep tracking of my downloads (as a pageview not an event) using Google Analytics...

I have 0 knowledge in programming, so I was reading this: https://neilpatel.com/blog/ga-virtual-pageviews/ and this person was using something like onClick="gaq.push(('_trackPageview','NAME',))", but I guess that is too old for me. Tried with this, but I think it's also old [Attach onClick analytics tracking code in a href link using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538143/attach-onclick-analytics-tracking-code-in-a-href-link-using-jquery)

So... my question is, on my website, for example if you go to https://www.tusubtitulo.com/episodes/74568/fear-the-walking-dead-6x02-welcome-to-the-club and click where it's says "Descargar", and then click where it's says : ¿No inició tu descarga? Presiona aquí. (where aquí contains the link), how can I add that (as page visit) on Google Analytics.

(Just in case, every download on my site has an unique download link)...

(Example of the programming on my site that generate the download link:

```
<a id="loadUpdate" href="updated/{{ langVersion }}/{{ id }}/{{ lversion }}">aquí</a>.
```

This is my code right now. It contains some code so I can count the visitors who are using adblocker, but I would like to know, how can I track my downloads as a page visit...

Google Analytics:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-171564499-1"></script>
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    // Creates an adblock detection plugin.
    ga('provide', 'adblockTracker', function(tracker, opts) {
        var ad = document.createElement('ins');
        ad.className = 'AdSense';
        ad.style.display = 'block';
        ad.style.position = 'absolute';
        ad.style.top = '-1px';
        ad.style.height = '1px';
        document.body.appendChild(ad);
        tracker.set('dimension' + opts.dimensionIndex, !ad.clientHeight);
        document.body.removeChild(ad);
    });

    // TODO: Replace UA-XXXXX-Y with you tracking ID.
    ga('create', 'UA-number', 'auto');
    ga('require', 'adblockTracker', {dimensionIndex: 1});
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **Universal Analytics** *Event* code, see the documentation to define event `category`, `action` and `label`: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

For example, you can send an event to Analytics when user click on your link replacing your link tag with the following:

```
<a id="loadOriginal" href="original/74568/0" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'download', 'download_clicked', 'fear the walking dead');">aquí</a>
```

If you want pageview just use that:

```
<a id="loadUpdate" href="updated/1/74568/0" onclick="ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);">aquí</a>
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. But I'm not searching for create an "event", I just need that as a page view...

Also... like I said, the href change for all of my downloads, so it's like I need to put there a varibale instead of a manual link.

Comment: I update the answer. Anyway the concept is the same, just put a dynamic variable as value (i.e. in the example location.pathname), or if you want the href value or other...

Comment: Thanks for answering, Michele. I'm curious, do I need to update my GA code? or you think it's not necessary?

Comment: Not necessary, you are using Universal Analytics that is the current stable version. The new GA4 is another story. In your code you are using '<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-171564499-1"></script>' I think you don't need it, so you can remove it. Mark answer as solved, pls.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll test soon and let you know, so then I will mark the problem as solved! thanks!